# uwp with c# and mvvm how to do inversion of control (dependency injection)

Tags: c#, .net-core, mvvm, uwp, inversion-of-control

so most of my progamming has been done in java where i used a lot of IoC and DPI by injecting all the necessary depencies to the constructors of the newly created objects from the main method.
so i injected all the repositories into the services, then the services into the controllers. in this way i only created one instance of each dependency and injected them wherever they were needed.

in java i do it like this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        InterfaceRepository<Booking> bookingInterface = new BookingRepository();
        InterfaceRepository<User> userInterface = new UserRepository();
        
        InterfaceBookingService interfaceBookingService = new BookingService(bookingInterface, userInterface);
        InterfaceUserService interfaceUserService = new UserService(userInterface);
        
        BookingController bookingController = new BookingController(interfaceBookingService, interfaceUserService);
        UserController userController = new UserController(interfaceUserService)

    }

}
```

in uwp i'm completely lost on how to do the same as i did in java. how and where are the viewmodels even instanced and how can i inject the repositories into the viewmodels; if some of my repositories are needed by several of the viewmodels, can i inject the same instance of the repositories to the different viewmodels? i want to be able to test my viewmodels, so i want to have the possibility to be flexible with what i inject as well.

i'm sorry i don't have any code, this is because i can't even get started coding in uwp with c# and mvvm without finding out how to be able to do IoC and follow the S.O.L.I.D. principles

Answer (score 0):

About MVVM in UWP, you could refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-and-mvvm). There are samples in the document you could view that where the viewmodles are instanced.

You could use **Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection** NuGet package to do the dependency injection.

Please check the following steps:
1.Create the MVVM architecture in a C# UWP project.
2.Click **Tools** in menu, select the option **NuGet Package Manager >  Manage NuGet Package for Solution… > Browse**, enter `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` in search box, install the package for your project.
3.Create `Container` object which maintains all of the dependencies that can be resolved anywhere in the application.

```
//App.xaml.cs
public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
    Container = ConfigureDependencyInjection();
}
public IServiceProvider Container { get; }

IServiceProvider ConfigureDependencyInjection()
{
    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

    serviceCollection.AddTransient<IMessageService, MessageService>();

    return serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
}
```

4.Create the `MessageService` class and the `IMessageService` interface.

```
//Add a new class to create the interface and class
public interface IMessageService
{
    string GetMessage();
}
public class MessageService : IMessageService
{
    public string GetMessage()
    {
        return "Hello from Message Service & Dependency Injection";
    }
}
```

5.Register `MessageService` to `Container`(referring to the code in **step 3**).
6.Inject `MessageService` into your viewmodel class such as `MainViewModel` class.

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    protected IMessageService MessageService { get; }
    public string Message { get => MessageService.GetMessage(); }
    public MainViewModel(IMessageService messageService)
    {
        MessageService = messageService;
        ……
    }
    ……
}
```

7.Resolve the `MainViewModel`, and inject the dependencies by using `ActivatorUtilities` function to inject parameters into the constructor.

```
//MainPage.xaml.cs
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    var container = ((App)App.Current).Container;
    DataContext = ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(container, typeof(MainViewModel));
}
```

8.Show the message in page.

```
//MainPage.xaml
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" Margin="10" FontSize="20"/>
</Grid>
```